# original job with many orders

Tags: sql

I've been at this for some time now and am trying to write another subquery to subtract [total contract] - [total cost]. Both of those subqueries run fine but I haven't been able to write another subquery to subtract both of them for a desired column of [profit]. Most of the time the queries I try just return saying the subquery has returned more than one value.. Any help is greatly appreciated! This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT MAN_PROD_ORDER.PROD_ORDER_NUM,
(SELECT SUM(SAL_SALES_ORDER.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX)
FROM SAL_SALES_ORDER
WHERE (SAL_SALES_ORDER.ORIG_SALES_ORDER_ID = MAN_PROD_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID or SAL_SALES_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID = MAN_PROD_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID)
      and SAL_SALES_ORDER.SAL_ORDER_STATUS_ID not in (6, 8)) as [total contract],
(SELECT SUM(PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY.TOTAL_COST) 
FROM PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY
WHERE MAN_PROD_ORDER.PROD_ORDER_ID = PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY.PROD_ORDER_ID AND PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY.ENTRY_TYPE_ID = 1) as [total cost]
FROM MAN_PROD_ORDER
```

Comment: please try to strucutre your SQLs - will be way easier to read for everybody

Comment: and have a look at one of the most basic things:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/19/introduction-to-joins/

Comment: sorry about that. I didn't realize it would come out looking the way it did... Will do better next time!

Answer (score 0):

Should work somehow like this:

```
SELECT MAN_PROD_ORDER.PROD_ORDER_NUM
      ,SUM(SAL_SALES_ORDER.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX) AS total_contract
      ,SUM(PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY.TOTAL_COST) AS total_cost
      ,SUM(SAL_SALES_ORDER.AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX - PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY.TOTAL_COST) as profit
  FROM MAN_PROD_ORDER 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SAL_SALES_ORDER
    ON (SAL_SALES_ORDER.ORIG_SALES_ORDER_ID = MAN_PROD_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID OR
        SAL_SALES_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID      = MAN_PROD_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID)
   AND SAL_SALES_ORDER.SAL_ORDER_STATUS_ID NOT IN (6, 8)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY
    ON MAN_PROD_ORDER.PROD_ORDER_ID = PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY.PROD_ORDER_ID 
   AND PROD_ORDER_LEDGER_ENTRY.ENTRY_TYPE_ID = 1
GROUP BY MAN_PROD_ORDER.PROD_ORDER_NUM
```